# Disk Image Writers on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

Are there any Disk Image Writers that I can download on Raspbian? If so, how can I download them through the terminal?

Comment: DD is already installed. You just need to be extra careful not to pick the wrong drive to write as you can hose your system.

Comment: @SteveRobillard I used the Disk Utility, which worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the Disk Utility as a disk image writer. It worked perfectly for me.